# Poisson Process conditional probability intersection?

Tags: conditional-probability, poisson-process

I've come across this type of problem a few times now so I understand what the correct steps are but I am struggling to understand the intuition behind this.  The example problem states:

> Consider a Poisson process on the interval [0, T] with rate λ > 0, and let 0 <
> τ < T. Define X1 to be the number of counts during [0, τ ], X2 to be the number of counts during
> [τ, T], and X to be the total number of counts during [0, T]. Let i, j, n be nonnegative integers such that n = i + j. Express the following probabilities in terms of n, i, j, τ, T, and λ, simplifying your answers as much as possible: Find P(X1 = i|X = n).

Steps to solve seem to be:

1. P(X1=i|X=n) = P(X1=i,X=n)/P(X=n)
2. P(X1=i,X-X1=n-i)/P(X=n)
3. P(X1=i,X2=j)/P(X=n)
   ...

I don't understand why step 2 is true.  Why is the intersection of X1=i and X=n equivalent to X1=1 intersected with X-Xi=n-1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event that there were $6$ arrivals before time $\tau$ and a total of $9$ arrivals is the same as the event that there were $6$ arrivals before time $\tau$ and $3$ arrivals after that time.

Comment: Ok, so that statement makes sense and it's helpful but I don't see how that's the same as equating the two intersections? I guess when i come across a problem like this, my first inclination is to want to try to understand how the two distributions overlap and then define the overlap as the intersection but the way you've worded it makes sense intuitively.  I would have thought that the intersection of the 2 events would have completely precluded X2 though given that X1 and X2 are disjoint.

Comment: @Bolpincal : It makes no sense to call $X_1$ and $X_2$ "disjoint." Disjointness is a property of EVENTS, NOT of RANDOM VARIABLES. The intersection of the event  $\Big\{ \text{“there were $6$ arrivals before time $\tau$”} \Big\}$ and the event  $\Big\{ \text{“there were $9$ arrivals in all”} \Big\}$ is the event  $\Big\{ \text{“there were $6$ arrivals before time $\tau$ AND $9$ arrivals in all”} \Big\}.$ And those two events are clearly not disjoint: it is possible for both to happen. $\qquad$

Comment: Likewise the event $\big\{ X_1=6\big\}$ and the event $\big\{ X_2=3 \big\}$ are not disjoint: the probability that both happen is not $0. \qquad$

Comment: But the intervals of time, $(0,\tau)$ and $(\tau,T),$ are disjoint. $\qquad$

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the intersection of X1=i and X=n equivalent to X1=1 intersected with X-Xi=n-1?

It is not.  You are confusing some $i$ and $1$.  (Wh1ch m1ght just be a typ0, but st1ll, be careful.)

---

Because $X$ is the total of counts over both periods, so $X=X_1+X_2$.   Thus $X_2=X-X_1$.

When $X_1=i$ and $X_1+X_2=n$ then $X_2=n-i$.  When $X_1=i$ and $X_2=n-i$ then $X_1+X_2=n$.

Therefore the event of $X_1=i$ and $X=n$ is the event of $X_1=i$ and $X_2=n-i$.

Since they are the same event, their probabilities are equal.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X_1=i, X=n) ~&=~ \mathsf P(X_1=i, X_2=n-i)\\
\end{align}$$